Responsive masonry layout with just three elements
I want to achieve an HTML/CSS template with three dynamic content divs such that

when #2 is non-blank (and in this case biggest of all) put #3 to the bottom of #1 and to the left of #2
when #2 is blank put #3 to the right of #1
on small screens, put everything in one column


AFAIU this is called a masonry layout and generally requires a JS library to implement.
But I wonder if a special case of just three elements is possible with some smart CSS trick and without Javascript?


.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 1em;
}

.box {
  width: 50%;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
  width: unset;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.media-sim {
  width: 30%;
}

.media-sim .box {
  width: 100%;
}
<div class='container'>
  <div class='red box'>
    <div style='margin: 5em'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='green box'>
    <div style='margin: 9em'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='blue box'>
    <div style='margin: 3em'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='container'>
  <div class='red box'>
    <div style='margin: 5em'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='green box'>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class='blue box'>
    <div style='margin: 3em'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='container media-sim'>
  <div class='red box'>
    <div style='margin: 5em'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='green box'>
    <div style='margin: 9em'>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='blue box'>
    <div style='margin: 3em'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



Result: blue in #1 goes to the bottom of top row, not to the left of green
Note: media-sim class here simulates the CSS @media query

EDIT someone suggested this to be a duplicate of CSS-only masonry layout which I think is fast and wrong because that question does not have a CSS answer and asks to solve any number of elements, not just three.
EDIT
Codepen link: https://codepen.io/anton-duzenko/pen/XWQYYGv
EDIT


What is to happen if #2 is not blank but is short.?

@AHaworth  does not matter really for my case

What is meant by #2 being blank? Does it exist at all or are there only two element now, red and blue? It would greatly help if you could show your HTML structure in these cases. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

From your edit: If you don't specify any more details, then there isn't much we can do. Unsure how "any number of elements" doesn't apply to three elements either. Instead of giving a sarcastic "thank you" comment you should provide more details

Masonry layouts are not currently possible in pure CSS, not even if you only have three elements. You'll have to do it in Javascript or change your design.

@AHaworth Just an empty div - i.e. the dynamic content is empty and the div is zero size

Are you in control of the HTML structure? If so, something can be done, but if not then it can’t with CSS alone.

@DarkBee you suggested a question that does not have a good answer because it's too general. It also does not cover the concept of responsive design. If that still counts as a duplicate, I reluctantly muck off.

@AHaworth I'm in control of the template, but not of the content HTML that goes inside the div's

Your question is general... Please add all details inside your question

"I'm in control of the template, but not of the content HTML that goes inside the div's" - what's your templating language? Does it not provide any sort of IF construct that would allow you to check if the variable content you put into the second div, is empty to begin with - so as not to output that div at all then?

If "empty" means really empty - not even white space, the second element would have to be <div class='green box'></div> - then you can target your container element based on that, using .container:has(.green:empty). So you could apply a different layout specifically in that situation - for example, using two different grid layouts for scenario #1 and #2.

@CBroe It's PHP, and I can indeed put and if in the template. Which is the workaround I would like not to fall back to.. Regarding your other comment, I'd like to also support the case of a few nested empty divs (which still results in an empty-size green box)

Please put code direct into your question and please show exactly what the situation is when green is 'blank' (e.g. does it have anything in it, like that p element you show, and what happens to its dimensions?)

@AHaworth sure, as soon as moderators unblock the question

Is editing disabled for you?

@AHaworth No, but answers are disabled, so moderators don't want people to answer it

Sorry, you have misunderstood the point of closing/opening. Once your question is clear enough that we feel it is well-formed and hopefully answerable, we (not necessarily moderators, just ordinary members) can vote to open it. We are trying to help you, please do as asked and we should be able to help you.
